# Is it possible to change the vpc and subnet of GCP instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created one gcp instance in default vpc. But now i knew that VM needed to created in another vpc.

So far, i have done lot of work on it. So creating new vm in other vpc and do same stuff there is not possible.

I have read somewhere that VPC can be selected only while creating instance. Can i change the VPC and Subnet of my instance ?

Comment: if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I change the VPC and Subnet of my instance ?
The short answer is Yes, you can.

If you already have your new VPC create you can follow the steps below if not you can consult the following documentation: [Creating networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#creating_networks)

To migrate a VM instance from one network to another.

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [VM instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) page.
2. Click the VM instance name to open the details page.
3. Click **Stop**.
4. If a confirmation dialog appears, click **Stop**.
5. After the VM stops, click **Edit**.
6. Under **Network interfaces**, click the interface you want to move.
7. In the **Network** field of the interface, select the new network for the interface.
8. In the **Subnetwork** field of the interface, select the new subnet for the interface.
9. In the **Internal IP address** field, specify **Automatic** if you want the system to allocate an IP address from the subnet range or **Custom** if you want to specify an unused one yourself.
10. Click **Done** to close the network interface edit panel.
11. Click **Save**.
12. After the VM finishes saving, click **Start**.
13. If a confirmation dialog appears, click **Start**.

Also you can execute this change by gcloud command line:

1. Stop the VM

```
gcloud beta compute instances stop INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=ZONE_NAME
```

2. Migrate the VM

```
gcloud beta compute instances network-interfaces update INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=ZONE_NAME \
    --network-interface=NIC \
    --network=NETWORK_NAME \
    --subnetwork=SUBNET_NAME
```

3.Start the VM

```
gcloud beta compute instances start INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=ZONE_NAME
```

Please check the following documentation for [further details](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/migrating-interfaces-between-networks)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **YES**. But you should stop the instance before moving to the other VPC otherwise you will not allowed to do so. You can change the VPC simply by using the console under `advance->networking`.